# Extracting data from HTML using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to use regular expressions to pull out something similar to the below string.  However, there will be multiple with different functions within the `data-plugin` attribute.

```
<div class="plugin" data-plugin="function(1,2,'func')"></div>
```

I was using an expression like the following:

```
/<div class="js-plugin" data-plugin="([a-zA-Z0-9\(\),\' ]*)"></div>/
```

However, this can't work as the string like `'func'` could include all sorts of special characters.

How can I use a regular expression to pull out the entire string, and match the contents within `data-plugin=""` as well as presuming there may be multiple matches.

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for this??

Comment: You will definitely want to read : [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175966)

Comment: Well, i've landed on some code im having to work on. It uses PHP, now im having to use regex to go through a massive HTML string and take out these functions so i can eval() them and the HTML replaces it and outputs to the page essentially.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex to get data from a html element. Select the element and use dom methods to get the data instead.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".plugin").getAttribute("data-plugin"));
```

```html
<div class="plugin" data-plugin="function(1,2,'func')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need regex, this should work.

Regex:

```
\bdata-plugin="([a-zA-Z0-9\(\),\']*)
```

Input:

```
<div class="plugin" data-plugin="function(1,2,'func')"></div>
```

Output:

```
function(1,2,'func')
```

```js
const regex = /\bdata-plugin="([a-zA-Z0-9\(\),\']*)/;
const str = `<div class="plugin" data-plugin="function(1,2,'func')"></div>
`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/FPH9O3/3

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.